# When is the constructor being called when performing + operation

Tags: constructor

Hi I am writing following code:

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

class Test
{
public:
int a;
Test();
Test(int b);
Test operator+(const Test t) const{Test ret; ret.a = t.a+a; return ret;}
};

Test::Test() {
    cout << "Null Constructor Called \n";
}
Test::Test(int b) {
    a=b;
    cout << "Assigned Constructor Called \n";
}


int main() {
    Test t1(1);
    Test t2(2);
    Test t3;
    t3 = t1+t2;
    return 0;
}
```

And get the following output:

> Assigned Constructor Called 
> Assigned Constructor Called 
> Null Constructor Called 
> Null Constructor Called 
> I would like to ask that for code:

```
t3 = t1+t2;
```

Why would it trigger the constructor? 
Any workaround to let it not trigger constructor?
Thanks a lot

Comment: This is passing by value vs passing by reference problem. operator+ takes its parameter "t" as value, so "t2" is copied (with default copy constructor). To prevent copying, you can use const reference as a parameter.

Comment: Test operator+(const Test &t)

Answer (score 0):

It's inside the overridden operator `+`. In your code you make a temporary `Test` object `ret`, use that to perform the addition, then return the result.  The call `Test ret` is the reason for the second `Null Constructor Called` output. This is normal behavior for using an addition operator in an assignment (see [here](https://www.codeproject.com/Tips/103648/C-Tip-How-to-eliminate-Temporary-Objects)).

Get around this by using initialization in `main` instead of assignment:

```
Test t3 = t1+t2;
```

Output is then

```
Assigned Constructor Called
Assigned Constructor Called
Null Constructor Called
```